# Topology exception on geometry intersection?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, self-intersection

I am using the following PostGIS functions in a Postgres query:

```
ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Intersection(p.geom,c.geom))
```

Where p.geom & c.geom are type multipolygon. The query works *most* of the time but with some layers I recieve the following error:

```
ERROR: Error performing intersection: TopologyException: Input geom 0 
is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point...
```

I tried applying `ST_Makevalid()` on the individual geometries in the ST_Intersection call but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

I also tried adding where conditions using `ST_IsValid()` on both table geometries and the intersection of the two. I can get the query working when I add `where ST_IsValid(p.geom)` but it excludes a large number of the features I'm trying to display in the application.

After running `ST_IsValidReason(p.geom)` I can see that several of the results have `Ring Self-intersection[{long} {lat}]`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data that is causing it? It is very possible that `ST_Makevalid()` so you might want to just exclude invalid input with `ST_IsValid()`.

Comment: @RoperMaps Unfortunately it would be difficult to provide the data since I'd have to share the entire tables. See edit, the offending geometry returns `Ring Self-intersection[...]` for validity reason.

Comment: Well you have to clean your input somehow. Can you post a representative sample of the output of [`ST_IsValidDetail`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html) called on affected geoms.

Comment: I think ST_MakeValid does this, but I assume you've tried a zero buffer? You can also do `ST_Buffer(ST_Buffer(geom, -0.001), 0.001)` which fills small slivers.

Comment: @RoperMaps so I updated the invalid geometry in the table using `set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)` and now its working. If you'd like to post your suggestion as an answer, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The input of `st_intersection` needs to be cleaned.

You can check whether geometries are clean by using:

`WHERE ST_IsValid(mySuspectTable.geom)`

You can try and fix these with:

`set geom = ST_MakeValid(geom)`

You can also use:

`ST_Buffer(ST_Buffer(geom, -0.001), 0.001)`

To remove slivers.